# what's the default implementation of JSObjectGetPropertyCallback?

Tags: javascriptcore

I'm building an JSObjectRef with both static functions and property variables, but I found that if I define the class like this:

```
    static JSStaticFunction myStaticFunctions[] = {
        { "myStFunc", JSAction::jsMyStFunc, kJSPropertyAttributeNone },
        { 0, 0, 0 }
    };
    JSClassDefinition classDef = kJSClassDefinitionEmpty;
    classDef.staticFunctions = myStaticFunctions;
    classDef.getProperty = jsPropertyGet;
    jsclass = JSClassCreate(&classDef);
    proto = JSObjectMake(cx, jsclass, NULL);
```

And when I'm calling the static function(myStFunc) in javascript, the getProperty callback(jsPropertyGet) is also invoked, but I don't know how to return the default action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it.

for JSObjectGetPropertyCallback, return `NULL` will get the request forwards to it's static properties, then parent class chain, and then prototype chain.

for JSObjectSetPropertyCallback, return `false` if you don't want to process it by yourself.